# Detección de outliers de un dataframe

Tags: python, jupyter

Tengo una pregunta referente a los datos outliers de un dataframe en python. Yo tengo una base de datos en la que tengo ciertas variables de ventas en las columnas y cada fila es un cliente. Mis clientes son mayores de edad. El problema que tengo es que al hacer la detección de los datos outliers por el método de tukey de la edad me sale lo siguiente:

```
[floor=14.000000, ceiling=62.000000]
```

No entiendo porque me sale 14 si todos mis clientes son mayores de edad. ¿Alguien sabe como solucionar esto?

Comment: Yo entiendo que la prueba de Tukey, al basarse en la hipótesis de que los datos de entrada siguen una distribución normal, aunque todos tus datos sean mayores a 18, la normal implica que _podrían_ aparecer datos menores de 18, por lo que el intervalo de confianza se extiende por debajo de 18. Si ya sabes que no es así en tu caso, puedes ignorar el límite inferior que te da Tukey y poner 18 en su  lugar.

Comment: Vale, gracias. No sabía que la prueba de Tukey se basaba en la hipótesis de normalidad. Probaré si mis datos cumplen normalidad. Muchas gracias!